# How can I concatenate an array index to change the style of a component depending on the index?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am using React Native to perform this action. I have these styles:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  tabStyle: {
    marginHorizontal: 10,
    marginTop: 20,
    borderRadius: 2,
  },
  tabStyle_0: {
    backgroundColor: '#ff5252',
  },
  tabStyle_1: {
    backgroundColor: '#3da7dc',
  },
});
```

And I have this function:

```
renderTabBar = props => (
    <View style={styles.tabBar}>
      {props.navigationState.routes.map((route, i) => {
        return (
          <TouchableOpacity
            key={route.key}
            // HERE IS WHERE I NEED TO APPLY THE FUNCIONALITY
            style={[styles.tabStyle, styles.tabStyle_`${i}`]}
            onPress={() => this.setState({ index: i })}
          >
            <Animated.Text style={{ color: '#ffffff' }}>
              {route.title}
            </Animated.Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        );
      })}
    </View>
  );
```

See I am doing this:
`style={[styles.tabStyle, styles.tabStyle_`${i}`]}`

But it is not working at all. I am getting this error

> TypeError: TypeError: styles.tabStyle_ is not a function

So all I need is to set the style of `TouchableOpacity` to `styles.tabStyle_0` or `styles.tabStyle_1` or `styles.tabStyle_2`.

How can I achieve what I need in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) when you use variable as property accessor.

Just change this

```
style={[styles.tabStyle, styles.tabStyle_${i}]}
```

to this

```
style={[styles.tabStyle, styles[`tabStyle_${i}`]}
```